# I want to run the python file multiple times by changing only the variable

Tags: python, variables, import, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In jupyter, If i import another Python file, the entire file is executed. After changing the variables, I want to execute the entire file in the same way.

file1.ipynb

```
a = 5
b = 2
print(a+b)
def change(changeA,changeB):
    a=changeA
    b=chnageB
```

file2.ipynb

```
import file1
file1.change(5,7)
**execute file1 again***
```

Comment: What is the question, please clarify your question.

Comment: after first import it shows all results, but after second import it shows nothing

Comment: You don't change the global variables `a` and `b`. You create new local variables with the same names and those are gone after you leave the function.

Comment: An imported file is executed when its first imported. Importing the file twice will not execute it again the second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have a file:

```
a = 5
b = 2
print(a+b)
```

And you want to re-run it with new variable values. You can use a function:

`file1`

```
def do_computations(a, b):
    return a + b
```

`file2`

```
from file1 import do_computations

do_computations(1,1)
do_computations(1,3)
```

If you really want the variables to be global (not recommended), you could do this:

`file1`

```
a = 5
b = 2


def do():
    print(a+b)
```

`file2`

```
import file1

file1.a = 5
file1.b = 5

file1.do()
```

The code you posted does not work between runs, when you change a variable, it only changes the value during that run. Running it again will start with the original value.

```
import file1
file1.change(5,7)
**execute file1 again***
```

And even if that worked, or you used it in the same run, you are declaring local variables for your function, they don't change the global variables. You must use the keyword global for that. Again, this approach is not recommended.

```
def change(changeA,changeB):
    global a
    global b
    a=changeA
    b=chnageB
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if I want to change a variable in an external file

Comment: in the external file, create a function which does the computations, then import it using `from name_of_the_file import do_computations` and call it

Comment: In fact, there are many functions, and only certain variables have to be changed and executed'n' times, but creating'n' files seemed inefficient.That's so difficult ㅜㅜ